# why mixed normal distribution has heavier tail than normal distribution?

Tags: probability

Who can give me a concrete example to illustrate the claim that
"mixed normal distribution would have heavier tail than just normal distribution".
Appreciate it!

Comment: What makes you think it is true?

Comment: Any source for this (dubious) claim?